# Creating taxonomy terms via REST API using POST: proper formatting of json?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, services, 9

On Drupal 9.4 here and I want to create taxonomy terms via the api. Is there a good example of what I need to POST to an API end point?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make sure you have taxonomy REST services enabled at: **/admin/config/services/rest**

From there, you need to just POST to the following url: **mydomain.com/taxonomy/term?_format=json**

The format of the json you need the following only: (fyi, its in javascript for a nodejs file running in the cli.)

```
const postData = JSON.stringify({
  vid: [{ target_id: 'vocabulary_name', target_type: 'taxonomy_vocabulary' }], 
  name: [{ value: "some name here" }], 
});
```

Just pass that data into https request. Keep in mind to add in your user / pass authentication.

```
const options = {                                                                                                                                                                                  
  hostname: 'mydomain.com',                                                                                                                                                                    
  path: '/taxonomy/term?_format=json',                                                                                                                                                             
  method: 'POST',                                                                                                                                                                                  
  headers: {                                                                                                                                                                                         
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',                                                                                                                                                              
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from('myuser:password').toString('base64'),                                                                                                              
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData),                                                                                                                                                 
  },                                                                                                                                                                                             };
```